# Destination paste range is selected on original sheet after copy

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a macro that copies Column H in Sheet1 into Column F in Sheet2, it works fine as intended, able to copy and paste all the values, however the range of Column F is selected in Sheet1 after running the macro and i don't know why or how to remedy it. Below is the macro i have, could any kind soul advice?

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
  Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    wsDest.Range("F2:F" & lDestLastRow).ClearContents
    wsCopy.Range("H7:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("F2")
End Sub
```

Comment: First question: Do you really need to use the copy/paste features which would be slower than just a `Range.Value` transfer?

Comment: Hi @JvdV, not necessary as long it fulfills the objective, I am quite inexperienced in VBA and the above code is actually researched and plucked from google, found it to be working well except for the aforementioned issue.

Comment: Avoid using Copy if you can, since it is way slower that just telling VBA to put the value of a range in another range. Check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your column F not to be selected you can just select another cell, let's say A1.
This would solve your problem of having the column selected (highlighted).

However, a there is a cleaner and faster way to Copy Paste which also doesn't select the Range after pasting it.

Just refer to your range and change its value using `range1.Value = range2.Value`, which will copy paste the values only. The idea is the same if you want to copy formats, of font size, etc. Just change the .Value with whatever property you want to copy/paste.
In your case, this would make:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
        Dim lDestLastRow As Long, nbvalues As Long
        
        Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
        
        lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        
        nbvalues = wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Range("H7"), wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
        wsDest.Range("F2:F" & lDestLastRow).ClearContents
        wsDest.Range("F2:F" & 2 + nbvalues).Value = wsCopy.Range("H7:H" & 7 + nbvalues).Value
End Sub
```

Note that for the last line, where VBA does the copy/paste, both ranges need to be the same lenght, which is why I use `lCopyLastRow` in both the source and the target range.

EDIT: In order to use `.Value=.Value`, both ranges need to be the same size. The `nbvalues` is a Long that represent the number of cells to paste in your other range, so `"F2:F" & 2+ nbvalues` is "Cell F2 to Cell F (2 + the number of cells to paste)"

Comment: Hi @romulax14 Thank you for your time, using .value method clears the whole column in both sheets tho, my intention is to update data in Sheet1 then transfer the latest updated data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 while keeping the data in Sheet1.

Comment: @Goodday .value does not clear the area it takes content from : `range1.Value =  range2.Value` keeps range2 untouched. I just inverted wsCopy and wsDest. I edited my post, try it again it works

Comment: @Goodday My code was telling excel to put wsDest (which was cleared) into wsCopy. My mistake, I changed it, it is wsCopy that must go into wsDest. Try my code again

Comment: Hi @romulax14 Thank you, your code solved the range selection issue, but it populated 5 rows of #N/A after the last row with value in the destination Sheet2, any idea why that is the case?

Comment: there are no formulas in my workbook or cells, tried pasting your code into a fresh new workbook and it returns the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220870/discussion-between-romulax14-and-goodday).

Answer (score 2):

`.Value=.Value` doesn't copy across formats. It will only copy across values. So if you want to copy across other stuff as well then this will not help. If you want to only copy values then go for `.Value=.Value` way.

Now to your question

> and i don't know why or how to remedy it.

**WHY**: These is no documented reason why this happens. If you are copying within the sheet then you will not see this problem. This happens only when you are copying across sheets. In fact this `Selection` is not even a valid selection. If you type `Debug.Print Selection.Address` before the copy and after the copy code, you will notice that it doesn't give you the address of newly selected range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Selection.Address
    Sheet1.Range("E6:E15").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("M6:M15")
    Debug.Print Selection.Address
End Sub
```

**HOW**: You can get rid of it by turning off ScreenUpdating.

Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    '~~> Sample Copy code
    Sheet1.Range("E6:E15").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("M6:M15")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Or a better way to write the same code as

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim currentScreenUpdating As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    '~~> Store Users current ScreenUpdating state
    currentScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    
    '~~> Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    '~~> Sample Copy code
    Sheet1.Range("E6:E15").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("M6:M15")
    
LetsContinue:
    '~~> Restore Users ScreenUpdating state
    Application.ScreenUpdating = currentScreenUpdating
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Siddharth Rout Thank you very much for your sharing, I tried the turning off screenupdating method but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tested it before posting. Type `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before `wsCopy.Range("H7:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("F2")` and then type `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. In th emean time let me see if I can upload a video demostrating it

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: @Siddarth Rout Thank you for the screenshot. I tried it, using the exact same code but its not working, really strange.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch between worksheets, the selected area disappears.

Try adding:

```
wsDest.Activate
wsCopy.Activate
```

as the last two lines in the `Sub` - it clears the selection.

Comment: I had already suggested that in the comments but deleted it as I wanted to avoid selecting and deselecting. Also this will give an error if the sheet that you are trying to select is hidden :)